# I want my drop down menu to be right aligned and not the default left align

Tags: css

need some help in this.
On hover I want the drop down ul to be align right and not left which is currently there
Please here
Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/kqZMf/4/

This is my css

```
ul, li, a {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Hi I want to add a down arrow to the first flyout.
http://www.spheretekk.com/ncf/ss.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.nav > li.hover > ul {
    left: auto;
    right:0;
}
```

Would this be what you are trying to do on first sub-level ?

http://jsfiddle.net/kqZMf/3/

Comment: How do I add an arrow on the drop down first flyout.

Comment: You could use the border technic on a pseudo element and draw a colored triangle. http://jsfiddle.net/kqZMf/5/

Answer (score 0):

You could float it right or use `position: absolute;`. Here's position: absolute example

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/kqZMf/1/

```
.main-nav {
    position: absolute;
    right:10px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
.main-nav {
    float: right;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqZMf/2/)**